# How to catch LightGBM training progress

Tags: python, lightgbm

I use LightGBM model and it's method [`train`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#lightgbm.train). And there is a parameter `verbose_eval=1` that prints LightGBM's progress.

```
lgb.train(params,dataset, verbose_eval=1)
```

I want to catch this progress (save in variable): I start train model from Flask, so I need to send this progress through REST API.

Is it possible?

P.S. One thing making my problem harder:  I use multiprocessing module (`Process`).  I run several models simultaniously.
So I can't use [@Mykhailo Lisovyi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55882694/4960953) approach: models will print into one flow. I can not determine which data from which model.

Answer (score 2):

You catch catch stdout and stderr directly. I used the solution from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/04b9064f005b8ebe704e7addbcc20973). I'm not experienced with the native training API. But using the sklearn API of lightgbm you can do:

```py
import sys
from io import StringIO

def capture_out(func):
    try:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        result = StringIO()
        sys.stdout = result
        func()
        result_string = result.getvalue()
        return result_string
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout

def fit_model():
    mdl.fit(train_X, train_y, **params_fit)

capture_out(fit_model)
```

where `mdl` is `lgb.LGBMRegressor`, train_X, train_y are numpy arrays, `params_fit` are parameters to configure early stopping

Comment: Tnank you for response! It's good answer and really solves the problem I asked. But really the problem a bit harder - I use it in multiprocessing module (`Process`) so this hint can't help me - I run several models simultaniously and they will print into one flow. I can not determine which data from which model

Comment: Uh, i see. The problem starts to be much more challenging. Sorry, i have no solution for such case :(